# Replacing nan with 0 error:nan not supported for input type

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which contains date and time as follows

```
a[0]=2014-06-01 03:14:34
```

I checked type of a[0]. It is given to be str.Some values in numpy array are nan. I have to replace nan with 0 and rest with 1. I tried isnan(a) but it gave me error:
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
What is wrong and how can I replace nan with 0?

Comment: When you say NaN, do you just mean the string `nan`? `isnan` does not support string arrays which you have here.

Comment: Yes. Thats problem. I tried converting string to int or float but it gave error. ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '2015-07-05 19:39:37'

Comment: How your nan statements look like?

Answer (score 10):

In order for your array to contain both strings and NaNs, it must be of object dtype. NumPy arrays of object dtype are not particularly efficient in terms of memory or performance. *There are no vectorized operations for object arrays*. The error message

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

is saying that `np.isnan` can not be applied to object arrays, and this object
array could not be coerced to a supported data type such as `np.float`.

Ideally, avoid building object arrays in the first place. But given that you
have this object array, to build the new array, you might as well just loop over
the items in `a` in a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['2014-06-01 03:14:34', np.nan], dtype='O')
b = np.array([item == item for item in a]).astype(int)
print(b)
```

yields

```
[1 0]
```

---

**How `item == item` tests for NaN**:

NaN has [the property that NaN != NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/190597). NaN is the only object in the pantheon of standard Python objects which has this property. Custom classes can be defined whose instances can also have this property. As long as `a` does not contains instances of such a custom class, you could use the `item != item` property to test for NaN:

```
In [43]: float('nan') != float('nan')
Out[43]: True

In [44]: np.nan != np.nan
Out[44]: True
```

Comment: " There are no vectorized operations for object arrays" does this imply that pandas dataframes are impossible to vectorize since all of their columns have dtype object?

Comment: @MikePalmice: Unlike NumPy, some [Pandas string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#working-with-text-data) are vectorized -- that is, the loop is sped up somewhat through the use of Cython. But strings are only one type of object. DataFrame columns of object dtype can hold *any* Python object. So it depends on what kind of objects you have in the DataFrame and what operation you are trying to perform.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to create array with preset size with `np.zeros` then fill the cells manually to create vectorized numpy array that I can use with `isnan`.

In the code below, `fields` contains list of field names used in object array.

```
v_data = np.zeros((o_data.shape[0], len(fields)))
for rcounter, row in enumerate(o_data):
  for fcounter, field in enumerate(fields):
    v_data[rcounter, fcounter] = row[field]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use function:

```
def replace_nan(num):
    if not numpy.nan_to_num(num):
        return 1
```

Comment: You don't need `else` here.

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''